# CakePHP - GoDaddy Shared hosting - HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

i have the following `.htaccess` configuration

```
####### In the root directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] 
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L] 

</IfModule> 


####### In the app directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L] 
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L] 
 </IfModule>


###### In the webroot
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

I am getting the following error

> HTTP ERROR 500

Error Logs from `GoDaddy`

```
[Thu Dec 01 05:33:59.885650 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 149973:tid 140591985846016] [client 85.17.24.76:43828] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/mink7/public_html/sites/prayag.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 918
[Thu Dec 01 05:33:59.885627 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 149973:tid 140591985846016] [client 85.17.24.76:43828] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/mink7/public_html/sites/prayag.mink7.com/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mink7/public_html/sites/prayag.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
[Thu Dec 01 05:33:59.878469 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 149973:tid 140591985846016] [client 85.17.24.76:43828] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mink7/public_html/sites/prayag.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
```

Comment: That means you have to check the error log to see what's wrong. In a shared hosting you often have a tool in the control panel.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález there is nothing in the error logs

Comment: What error logs does GoDaddy offer? Apache, PHP or both?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yeah both :( any place where i can start looking? if it throws any error it would have been easier

Comment: I'm afraid I can only suggest what you've probably figured out yourself: try out one thing at a time and see when it starts 500ing. Sorry.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález okay i got the logs to work. have updated the log entries in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is hosted at:

```
/home/mink7/public_html/sites/prayag.mink7.com
```

However, CakePHP is trying to load stuff at:

```
/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web
```

You must have hard-coded a wrong path somewhere in your configuration.

Comment: damn!! it was the cached files from the previous hosting :(